# fresh to java (arrays and prime numbers) need help fixing issue

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

i have to have an array of 1000 numbers (1- 1000)and sort out the prime numbers and print just those from the array. i have to use 4 methods while doing this:

//publicstaticvoidmain(String[] args)  //calls on int[] a

//publicstaticvoid init(int[] a)

//publicstaticvoid findPrimes(int[] a)

//publicstaticvoid printPrimes(int[] a)

i have it almost done i think but i just cant quite get it to search and print the prime numbers, i keep printing the wrong values, sorry for the mess of code in advance i try to put side notes to keep track. ps. im very new and very bad at java

```
    class findPrimes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[]a = new int [1001];
        init(a);
        findPrimes(a);
        printPrimes(a);


    }

    public static void init(int[]a){        
        for(int i = 2; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = 1;
            boolean isprime = true;
        //  System.out.println(i);
        }

    }


    public static void findPrimes(int[] a){
                for (int i = 2; i < a.length; i++){

                    }
                }       
        for (int j = 2*i; j <= a.length; j = j+i){
            int ind = j * i;
            if (ind>= a.length)
            a[i] = 0 ; 




    }
    }               
           }
    public static void printPrimes(int[] a){
            for(int i = 2; i < a.length; i++){
            if(a[i] == 1) {
                if (i%j == 0){
                    prime = false;
                    break;

                    System.out.print(i + ", ");
                }



    }
}   }
```

Comment: What's the problem? “i just cant quite get it to work properly“ it's far too broad and vague.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to implement *Sieve of Eratosthenes* algorithm, but your code is a bit messy.

Use this [link >>](http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Number_theoretic/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) please for explanations around the algorithm, it also includes implementation in *Java*, so solution will look like this:

```
public class FindPrimes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        runEratosthenesSieve(1000);
    }

    private static void runEratosthenesSieve(int upperBound) {
        int upperBoundSquareRoot = (int) Math.sqrt(upperBound);
        boolean[] isComposite = new boolean[upperBound + 1];
        for (int m = 2; m <= upperBoundSquareRoot; m++) {
            if (!isComposite[m]) {
                System.out.print(m + " ");
                for (int k = m * m; k <= upperBound; k += m) {
                    isComposite[k] = true;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int m = upperBoundSquareRoot; m <= upperBound; m++) {
            if (!isComposite[m]) {
                System.out.print(m + " ");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

If you want explanations around the mistakes in your code, we can discuss them too.

Comment: im sure there are way to many mistakes to count, without using the Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm (as its pretty complicated and has alot of terms i dont recognize(yet)) can i get the same effect with what i have?

my goal right now is to set all the values in the array to 1 and then find and set prime numbers to 0 then print the primes

Comment: @Gmob, you are trying to do the same thing in your _FindPrimes_ class, it is the simplest algorithm in terms of finding prime numbers, please check the GIF from Wikipedia for additional details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes